# What is the reason for the apparent lag of a mouse pointer when running a Linux Desktop?

Tags: linux, x11, mouse, gui

So this question might at first seem a little vague and it's most certainly not trolling or having a dig at Linux.  It's always been my observation that most Linux based desktop GUIs seem to have draggy style mouse pointer.  The experience of moving the mouse seems to be a slower to update of the cursor position.

It's almost as if there is a albeit very subtle lag between the GUI interface and the underlying OS.  On other operating systems such as Windows XP I notice the operating system seems to have a more seamless integration of the mouse GUI experience with the underlying OS, presumably because the OS is wired to the UI as one.

From a technical perspective I believe there must be a technical reason for this and if I had to have a guess I'd say perhaps something to do with the X windowing system communicating mouse cursor position via a local server X server?

Could someone give a technical explanation for this?

Comment: I've never noticed this, except when using a GUI over the network or in a VM (where the cause is obvious). But given that you're comparing Linux and Windows, did you install the correct graphics driver under Linux? If it's running in VESA mode while Windows has a proper driver, then that might be the reason.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a compositing window manager on hardware that isn't quite capable; comparing this to XP where there are absolutely no effects enabled isn't very fair then. I use (and have used) fvwm as my window manager like forever (at least 20 years!) and it's super responsive, much faster than even XP.

Comment: Have you observed this on more than one computer? More than one window manager?